# How to handle possible NULL correctly?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

While reading several different API codes I discovered that they handle possible nulls on different ways. And here at stackoverflow I have read several recommendations like no need for explicit checking or check and throw some meaning full exception...etc.

Say the method is something like this:

```
public void runThis(SomeObject obj){
  ## null handling code comes here ##
  obj.doSomething() <- possible NPE
}
```

The most common solutions I have seen:
**1.Throwing explicit NPE**

```
if(obj==null){
  throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

**2.Throwing custom exception**

```
if(obj==null){
 throw new CustomException("Null not allowed here");
}
```

**3.Using Assert (have seen it only once)**

```
assert obj!=null
```

**4.Do nothing and java will throw it when invoking doSomething()**

```
//
```

Is there some general - best all over the place -  solution to this?

Comment: For documentation sake there are the annotations `@nullable` and `@nonNull` which you can use on individual parameters. These will not affect logic, but will give a hint to the IDE when for example calling it with a `null` parameter. So developers can adjust their code at forehand.

Comment: examples you showed all works, personal i love ternary operator null checks.  for example String name = givenName == null ? "No name" : name;

Comment: You'd already get an NPE. Whatever happens should be domain-specific: if it's a parameter then you could check it and throw an illegal argument. If it's invalid state then maybe an illegal state exception. If it's recoverable or these don't capture the meaning then an app-specific exception. TL;DR: It's highly dependent on actual requirements, and often a matter of opinion.

Comment: @n247s advice is good. annotations does it best. + in Objects class you can find a method @requireNonNull() to get non null objects as needed.

Comment: If by "API" you mean something like a REST API invoked remotely, then you will (I hope) be validating input. It is useful to have explicit null checks because from the client's view, what they often did was "forget to provide a field in the message" rather than "pass null".  Furthermore, a server-side stack trace won't help them diagnose their mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some general - best all over the place - solution to this?

**No**.

This is because `null` doesn't have a commonly agreed meaning. It might be a result of a bug, indicate  missing data, or represent a default value.

Here are some tips:

- [requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) is better than writting `if (x == null)` everywhere.
- [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)
- Failing fast is good, so do throw an exception if you encounter an unexpected null. `NullPointerException` is fine, `IllegalArgumentException` is also ok. Bike sheds should be painted black.
- Don't use asserts - this is a dead language feature.
- Don't mask null values (it's like ignoring errors).

If you are looking for a solution that solves the null problem once and for all, I would like to take this opportunity to promote [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) - a programming language which does a good job of clearing up this mess. The null problem basically dissapears in Kotlin, yet at the same time it is easy to migrate from Java.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you got `obj`, and what you plan to do with it.

- Exceptions should be used to check for invalid values in user input, and invalid values passed to public/protected methods.
  This is to ensure that your method can safely execute, and to provide a helpful message if it can't. Use custom exceptions for this purpose.
- Assertions should be used to check things that you believe should always be true. They are a tool to find bugs in your code, seeing as they're usually disabled in release builds.
  The most common use of assertions is in tests.